# Add RESTful endpoints to Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, routes

I have a rails application that just uses the default, catch all route currently. This works fine for regular HTML requests.

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
```

I would like to expose CRUD functionality to mobile clients. So how do I extend what I already have to support restuful requests (JSON)? Should I just add resource routes to my route.rb before the default route? Or should I stop using the default route in favor of resource routes? I suppose another option could be to specify the restful routes explicitly using match. This seems wrong however.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of whatever else you decide, you really should consider ditching the default catch-all route. Explicitly stating your routes gives you many advantages, such as [named routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for your views and serving as documentation as to what actually is happening in your routes.

Now, technically, you shouldn't really need to adjust the referenced route at all to handle most requests, regardless of the format (as long as it isn't too deep /like/this/route/is). The resources routes are fine in most cases, and are a good starting point, but I've actually come to prefer explicitly stating all of the routes as you've referred to. It is slightly more verbose, but it does offer several advantages. The first advantage is performance. Fewer routes means faster routing, and explicitly stating your routes can highlight opportunities to remove unused routes. Another advantage to this method is the additional configurability it provides. You may be able to send two REST-ful routes to the same controller action, due to a duplication of logic that would lead to a less DRY controller/view. Finally, in much the same way as removing the catch-all route does, it serves to act as live documentation for your routes. Never again will you need to drop to the console to run a `rake routes` command to see what is going on with your routing. I like the rails magic as much as the next guy, but I feel that this is one of the few areas that additional verbosity is welcome in my rails apps.

Comment: Awesome insight. Thanks for this through reply.